# Extract information about certificate from a .pfx file without the password

Tags: certificates, cryptography, openssl, pfx

Im trying to find a way to retrieve specific information about a certificate (expiration date, fingerprint etc) without the need to provide the password to decrypt the private key.

Just to be clear, I have no need to decrypt the private key, or obtain any information about or from it, only from the certificate.

Is this possible via openssl?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the file is actually encrypted (its optional - at least in the file spec) I don't believe so.

Newer .pfx files are [PKCS Archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12). These support encryption both at the file and container level - but seeing as the entire key would be in a single container I don't believe it would be possible.